# Plotly, scatter plot: what are the possible options for the dash entry in the line dictionary?

Tags: plotting, plotly

For example using some code like this one:

```py
fig.add_scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines', line=dict(dash='dot'))
```

The possibilities I know of are 'lines', 'dash', 'dot' and 'dashdot'. I was looking for another way to differentiate a new plot using this option, like "spaced dots" for example. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything where I looked (basically web searches and plotly line chart documentation). Is there any other possible value for this argument or is that all there is?

Answer (score 3):

When I put an invalid value to the 'dash' property, *plotly* shows an error message that list all the admissible values:

> The 'dash' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
>
> ```
>  - One of the following dash styles:
>
>        ['solid', 'dot', 'dash', 'longdash', 'dashdot', 'longdashdot']
>
>  - A string containing a dash length list in pixels or percentages
>
>        (e.g. '5px 10px 2px 2px', '5, 10, 2, 2', '10% 20% 40%', etc.)
> ```

This answers my question entirely.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).